# You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme

Tags: java, android, xml

Yes, I know, this problem was posted again and again here. But I can't find any solution to my specific problem.

Every time I try to make a Snackbar, my App crashes with

> You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with the
>   design library.

---

Ok. I know: no debugging without the code, so:

> The call, and line that throws the error:

```
Snackbar.make(
    new CoordinatorLayout(getApplicationContext()),
    "Logged out.",
    Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

> The class definition:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
```

> Beginning of the manifest

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".SplashActivity"
        android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.searchable"
            android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
    </activity>
```

---

Oh yeah: The AppTheme and AppTheme.NoActionbar are both parents of Theme.AppCompat...

If you need anymore code, just tell me.

Comment: Add `res/values/styles.xml` and `res/values-v21/styles.xml` (if you have it),  please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you need `CoordinatorLayout` with `getApplicationContext()`?

You might even be able to make it work with `new CoordinatorLayout(MainActivity.this)`. (this uses `Activity` `Context` instead of `Application` `Context`.

But you should really keep it simple. Try this:

```
Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content), "Logged out.", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```